# Is there a way espresso tests will continue from the next test on app/process crash?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-testing, android-espresso

I have an app with 50 espresso tests. On 10th test, app crashes and rest of the tests wont execute. Is there a way we can restart app and execution start from the next test?

Comment: Fix the app, it should not crash.

Comment: there must be a way to handle the crash.

Comment: You will probably have to write a try/catch and have a way to store the state of which test it crashed on.  Maybe use shared preferences and have some value represent each test. For your case maybe have the value 10 represent test #10.  when you begin your app on re-run have a conditional check for the state and continue where you left off. of course this requires a good amount of added code so there may be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You could run your tests using the Android Test Orchestrator, add the below into your build.gradle. Android Test Orchestrator allows you to continue running tests after crash.
More info here https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner
`android.defaultConfig {
testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
}
android.testOptions {
        execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
dependency: androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no way to run some specific test methods, you should run all or just one of them. The only way to handle crashes is using `try catch()`, in your case it may be helpful.